# Camera API for a Windows 8 Tablet on Visual Studio Express 2013 (For Windows Desktop)

Tags: camera, visual-studio-2013, desktop, windows-8.1, tablet

I want to write a program for my tablet using Visual Studio Express 2013 (for Windows Desktop). The tablet is running Windows 8.1 Pro.

For compatibility and ease of programming, I would like to continue working in VS Express 2013 for Windows Desktop.

I want my program to use the device's camera capture functionality. I would hope that this would be as simple as using libraries/APIs that are already widely known. However, all of the documentation and help forum posts I have read so far suggest that WIA (Windows Image Acquisition) was the library to use for desktops and Windows Media Capture must be used for Windows 8.1.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Update 2014-03-12: I am pursuing a different solution. I will try to build a website that can run on both platforms. This will be difficult as I have much less web-dev experience. I will try to keep updating until I have a satisfactory fix.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is specify a CaptureElement and a Button to capture the Picture as Shown Below

```
    <CaptureElement x:Name="cap1" Height="300" Width="450"/>
    <Button Content="Take a Photo" x:Name="btnCapture" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Click="btnCapture_Click"/>
```

Here is the Code Behind the Button :

```
      private async void btnCapture_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var _MediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
        await _MediaCapture.InitializeAsync();
        cap1.Source = _MediaCapture;
        await _MediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
    }
```

Remember that you need to use the Async and await keywords as this process is Asynchronous .

Comment: Maybe I don't understand, or maybe you don't. It appears to me that the [CaptureElement Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.captureelement.ASPx) is a member of the Windows API reference for Windows Store apps. I can not develop a Windows store app from a machine running Windows 7 because I cannot install VS for Windows (only VSE for Windows Desktop which doesn't let me reference those libraries).

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211384.aspx) is more clarification. I'm pursuing a workaround using websites instead.

Comment: For windows forms there is only WIA library , well.. does VSE for desktop provide the ability to develop WPF applications ? i guess it's another choice you can consider . sorry for the misunderstood question in the beginning .

Comment: VSE for desktop does support WPF development. Does this make some reference available to me that is mutually supported by Windows 8.1 and Windows 7?